# Find an element in the array that is less than M next elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Task:

Find an element in the array size N is less then M next elements in this array.

```
Here is algorithm:
a[0]<a[1] => true, then
a[0]<a[2] => false, then
a[2]<a[3] => true, then
a[2]<a[4] => true, then
... => always true
a[2]<a[m+2] => true then return a[2] //a[2] is minumum, m+2<n
```

My implementation doesn't work. Loop seems to be endless.

```
int[] array = new int[]{-1, 2, -3, 5, 0, 6, 9, -1, 5, 7, 8, 1};
int numElements = 5;
int i=0;
int j=1;
int result;

while (i+j < array.length){
if (array[i]<array[i+j]){
     if (i+j == numElements){
       result = array[i];
     } else j++;
   } else {
    i += j;
    j = 1;
    }
  }
```

My output should be -3.

There is no current output: endless loop.

Comment: Add more information like _input_ , _desired output_ and _current output_.

Comment: Why your output should be `-3`, a little explanation will do. Do you want the second minimum element in your array?

Comment: Are you using `arr` or `array` for the variable name?  Also~ you should take `j++` out of your if else block so that it executes each time `arr[i]<arr[i+j]`.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I want to find the first element for which one next 5(M) elements should be greater. -3 is less than 5,0,6,9,-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `arr[i] < arr[i+j]` is false, you should be...

1. resetting `j` to `1`
2. setting `i` equal to `i+j`

You should also add a check within the `while` loop condition to ensure `i+j < arr.length`

Finally~ take `j++` out of your `else` block.

```
while (i+j < array.length && r){
    if(array[i]<array[i+j]){
        if(i+j == numElements){
            result = array[i];
            r = false;
        }
        ++j;
    }
    else{
        i += j;
        j = 1;
    }
}
```

When I implemented this in C++, I got the correct output of `-3`.

Comment: You are right, but this doesn't solve the problem. My loop seems to be infinite.

Comment: @AndreiSh the `while` loop should stop when `result` is updated, correct?  In that case- I might suggest adding a `boolean` flag to indicate you've found the number that is less than the next M numbers.

Comment: I've removed my first else condition and it's worked! Thank you!

Comment: @AndreiSh you're welcome.  Once `i+j == numElements` was `true`~  `j` was never incremented which created an infinite loop of updating the `result` variable.  Glad I could help! :)

Comment: @AndreiSh by the way- this is a little late to add but `if(i+j==numElements)` should actually be `if(j==numElements)` since `j` represents the M next elements.  Adding them together may cause the condition to return true prematurely, particularly if the index you're comparing the M next elements with is `>= numElements`